# Packaging binary release on OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd, packaging

I have a tiny application written in go and I've cross-compiled it to various operating systems.

Currently my `Makefile` generates `myapp-VERSION-OS-CPUARCH.tar.gz` packages to be used as a source binary packages for to be released as `.deb`, `.rpm`, `PKGBUILD`, FreeBSD binary release `.tgz` and so on with a structure like so:

```
bin/myapp
LICENSE
README.md
```

I can't find tutorials/howtos/examples on how to package this into official OpenBSD `.tgz` binary release package(s). [pkg_create](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.6/pkg_create.1) seems to be the command, but I can't find examples.

So how you make the binary release package on OpenBSD so that there's all the metadata such as maintainer, application category, architecture and such?

The idea here is not getting the package to any official ports repository. It's to simply package a release for your own machine and learning about the packaging process on OpenBSD.

Comment: Maybe this will help : https://jmorano.moretrix.com/2016/03/ossec-building-an-openbsd-package/

Comment: I have to mention that your current working seems to indicate that your application is close source.

Comment: @OlegLobachev It is open source. How it relates to the question?

Comment: Because a source-based distribution seems much easier. Just let OpenBSD maintainers do their OpenBSD stuff on their own. Debain, too.

Answer (score 8):

The information you need is available in the [Porter's Handbook](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/ports/index.html) (more specifically the [Porting Guide](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/ports/guide.html) therein).

The summary is that you (if you want to create an official OpenBSD port) would not create a binary package yourself, but a port (a Makefile that slots into OpenBSD's port building infrastructure, and associated metadata files) that eventually gets accepted by the committers on the `ports@openbsd.org` mailing list.

After being committed, binary packages are then built, signed and distributed by the OpenBSD team using the port that you've written.

If you are not interested in building a package accessible through the official OpenBSD channels and would prefer to distribute your OpenBSD package with your software yourself, you would still have to fit it into the OpenBSD port infrastructure in the way described in the Porting Guide to be able to build that package.

How you go about building an OpenBSD port for some software is a too big topic to answer on this site. Try asking questions about specific issues that you come across while doing this instead.  You could also ask on [the `ports@openbsd.org` mailing list](https://www.openbsd.org/mail.html).

Comment: Just a tiny unrelated and unimportant question, doesn't this maken OpenBSD a bit less open? This seems to be going much further than a required route to get software into an official OS release, or does it involve a (security) feature that I'm awfully unaware of?  // Edit: does it have to do with the idea that communcation goes a long way to avoid duplicate software being developed of which none sees it through long-term?

Comment: @Mr.Donutz I'm not sure I understand your question. Why would it make OpenBSD less open? They are an open source project developed by volunteers. They are not obliged to accept anyone's software into the ports tree just because they are open source.

Comment: What if it's native software you're building from scratch for only OpenBSD? You need to some how create the packages and test the installation process also. You need all the things you mentioned before writing a line of code?

Comment: It's just this impression that I got, that "it is difficult to find out how to properly build binaries for OpenBSD". Not accepting such binaries is a whole different thing and, indeed, even necessary to some extent to ensure stable operation of a "default" bundle, like Debian Stable distro does (and which is why that software is not most up-to-date). So the opportunity to build binaries that can be provided 'stand-alone' is one thing, accepting them as part of a standard package is a whole different thing. Perhaps I just need to inform myself a bit more. So thanks for linking to that guide.

Comment: @raspi No, you build your software first, then you package it. This works the same as packaging from most other systems.  The ports framework is just a wrapper around whatever build system your software would ordinarily use to build.  You may want to look at other port that build software written in Go, for example [`sysutils/restic`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/ports/sysutils/restic/) (a backup program).

Comment: @Mr.Donutz Just building binaries on OpenBSD is _easy_.  It's after all just a Unix like any other. Producing binary bundles of software that anyone can install on their system using the package manager requires that you package it with the tools provided for that end. In OpenBSD's case, that means writing a port. On macOS running Homebrew, it means writing a "formulae" in Ruby. Etc. To make the packaged software part of an official repository, you would have to convince someone to commit it.

Comment: _"Just building binaries on OpenBSD is easy."_. It's probably even easier than for most other *nix, since everything is so standardized and everything you need is already in base.

Comment: @pipe Is `go` (the language) in base now?

Comment: @mosvy It is not. And it's unlikely to end up in the base system any time soon. It's available as port/package though.

Comment: I still can't find a good howto update an existing port. does anyone know ?

Comment: @AlexanderBr. I'm absolutely certain that people on the `ports` mailing list would be able to help you ([`ports@openbsd.org`](https://www.openbsd.org/mail.html)).  This site is no place for tutorials.